# Access-Control-Allow-Origin on a single Rails route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, cors

In my Rails app, I'm building a feature that allows users to embed data from the app on other sites using a Javascript snippet.

My Javascript snippet makes a GET request to a route in my rails app that returns raw JSON. When snippet and the JSON share the same domain, everything works well, but I'm running into CORS issues when I embed the snippet on another site.

Using the solution [I found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25045681/xmlhttprequest-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-request), I've begun configuring my Rails app for CORS.

In my `application_controller.rb`:

```
before_filter :add_allow_credentials_headers

def add_allow_credentials_headers
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = request.headers['Origin'] || '*'   
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'] = 'true'
end 

def options
    head :status => 200, :'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' => 'accept, content-type'
end
```

In my `routes.rb`:

```
get 'embed_json' => 'application#options', :via => [:options]
```

However, when I hit the above route in my browser, the app no longer returns the JSON object—just a blank screen.

There seem to be a number of conflicting approaches on how best to handle CORS on a single Rails route. Is there a "Rails way" to handle this requirement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A call to `head` won't return JSON [by definition](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Head.html#method-i-head). The options hash, when you call it with `head` will be converted into headers.

Might try this instead, an `options` call will give the headers as needed with an empty response body. A call to `index` should render JSON, along with the headers you set in the `add_allow_credentials_headers` filter.

```
def add_allow_credentials_headers
  response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = request.headers['Origin'] || '*'   
  response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'] = 'true'
  response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'accept, content-type'
end 

def options
  head :ok
end

def index
  # do something here that renders a JSON response
end
```

Also, another option for enabling CORS on your rails app is [rack-cors](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors), might do what you need without the hassle of doing it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Add `status: :ok` to the raw JSON you are returning. In case you return an empty body, add `head :ok` to return a 200 status

To only enable CORS for `options` method, what you can do is:

```
before_filter :add_allow_credentials_headers, only: [:options]

def add_allow_credentials_headers
  response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = request.headers['Origin'] || '*' # the domain you're making the request from
  response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'] = 'true'
  response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'accept, content-type'
end 

def options
  # your json response here or just 'head :ok' if empty 200 response
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Install this gem:

```
gem 'rack-cors', :require => 'rack/cors'
```

Then add this to your config/application.rb file.

```
module YourApp
  class Application < Rails::Application

    # ...

    # Rails 3/4

    config.middleware.insert_before 0, "Rack::Cors" do
      allow do
        origins '*'
        resource '*', :headers => :any, :methods => [:get, :post, :options]
      end
    end

    # Rails 5

    config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
      allow do
        origins '*'
        resource '*', :headers => :any, :methods => [:get, :post, :options]
      end
    end

  end
end
```

this will do the trick read more. [Cors](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors)

Comment: This will allow CORS on all routes. If you want to expose a single route, then you need to change the first resource argument from * to the endpoint:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43427080/how-to-enable-cors-for-only-selected-route-rails